# Reject input if another cell is empty - google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to reject input 'submit' in "Status" column if "format" or "status" column is empty.

- "Status" column have data validation drop down list so I can't use data validation to reject status input. I'm seeking for google script to do that.
- I need to use column header "status", "format", "Channel" into code to ensure that code working correctly if column index change.
- Show popup mess to warning that user need to fill "channel" and "format" before change status to
  'submit'

| No. | Channel | Format | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | Channel 1 | Format 1 | Submit |
| 17 |  | Format 1 | Process |
| 16 | Channel 2 | Format 2 | Process |
| 16 |  |  | Initial |

**Update code working correctly**

```js
function reject2_onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var status_col = headers.indexOf('Status')+1;
  var format_col = headers.indexOf('Format')+1;
  var channel_col = headers.indexOf('Channel')+1;

  if (e.range.getColumn() == status_col) {
    const row = parseInt(e.range.getRowIndex())
    if (e.value == "Submit") {
      if (ss.getRange(parseInt(row), format_col).getValue() == "" || ss.getRange(parseInt(row), channel_col).getValue() == "") {
        // Added the old value
        ss.getRange(row, status_col).setValue(e.oldValue)
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("PLEASE FILL THE FORMAT AND CHANNEL")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `input submit`?

Comment: @Cooper input "submit" I mean the text from dropdown list is "submit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onEdit()` trigger so that every time the `Status` column is edited it checks the status of `Channel` and `Format` to make sure they are not empty.

Here is an example:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  ss.getRange(7, 1).setValue(e)
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 4) {
    const row = parseInt(e.range.getRowIndex())
    if (e.value == "Submit") {
      if (ss.getRange(parseInt(row), 2).getValue() == "" || ss.getRange(parseInt(row), 3).getValue() == "") {
        // Added the old value
        ss.getRange(row, 4).setValue(e.oldValue)
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("PLEASE FILL THE FORMAT AND CHANNEL")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

###### Documentation

- [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) Trigger
- [Google Sheets events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)
- Classes [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: I have test your code, yes it working and can show alert "PLEASE FILL THE FORMAT AND CHANNEL" but still let user fill status submit after show alert. Can we get the previous value before value change to submit and set previous value if channel or format ="".

Comment: I edit my answer, now should work as you expect

Comment: thanks for your replying. It working perfect. I also using column header to make sure your code working correctly when column index change. Update on my post question. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please consider marking my answer as accepted.